# Merge an interface from a const with a generic function into a generic interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a bunch of legacy code following a pattern with a `const` like this:

```
const fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf = {
    equalityComparer<T>(a: T, b: T) { return a === b },
    otherFn<T> (this: T) { /*...*/ },
    // ... other things, all along the lines of `method<T> (...)`
} as const
```

I'd like to know how to merge the `typeof fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf` into a generic interface that "flattens" all the functions to the generic type of the interface extending it. e.g.

```
type Proto = typeof fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf

interface SuperProto<T> extends Proto {
    equalityComparer (a: T, b: T): boolean
}
```

This would greatly speed up and simplify adding types to an existing Javascript codebase (Knockout/TKO).

However, it gives the error:

> Type `(a: T, b: T) => boolean` is not assignable to type `<T>(a: T, b: T) => boolean`.

I've tried various type mappings e.g. `type Proto<T> = { [key in keyof typeof fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf]: fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf<T>[key]?? }` to set/pass along the generic property, but nothing has yet worked.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is a bit harder, namely multiple inheritance of `fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf` and `SuperProto<T>`, as it manifests in the [Knockout Observable type](https://github.com/knockout/tko/blob/f2ef57935dd6f79bf5043021772e87092a0a9399/packages/observable/src/observable.ts#L183) in the Knockout/TKO library.

I've a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=75#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAqhApgEwJJgMoqgBQCcQoSBPABxQHk4YBeGAbwCgZ2YUBHAVwEMANgEsoZAMIgAthT6EUhADwAVAHwAKPgC4YSgDQwARtqUBKZjDlQehMDD4N6jAzAC+uthwD0nzr0EjxKRk5RSUGOzAydS0dfSMdMyYLPGtbe0cnV3cOGBIAC3kAMTBlFRg1KDyhCGNEmE8AKgA6FoafNxYXOwgYUEgoFhZRKhgiEhBw4ZQQOgRkdCxcAmJSKdoWbxgp0ZWQJVLw1k2cgG0AaxQyGCFbC7IZnfGAXW0x0nPLp9KN9sGbqHkcD4wBQMGwPCohDeIAOKAAHgCwGgetDmB52Nx+MJRBJpLJ5OUYnpDLVtAYQCABCg+GB0fUfJj-DigvjQmUNMY4qTDBSqTTOn8wADCECQTAxFUBJhpFTJCghXwoEJwLCEfLkY9SPpwZDoQdWDlNozsYE8SEFIh2TFEFyYIgTGTedTaYaGX4TbjgvILeFVITtDaSXaHTzKc66Ub3QFPayffDERq-Ry7bb7Y6w-ycsboyyQv7YkHTOm+bSXINNkoqj0IHkQDwpTAAOZCABuoPs23kxEIuToACJCH3rj0wCRuhAhI2wHwDFSthMwDxJAZ5JoWH1oDA4eE1C3tBKhFKMDKUHKFUqVYvl-IVGZ6GUW01s8yzfI1AByQjv-TvrjvkxAA) that illustrates the problem (among various attempts to fix it).

#### Edit:

Second [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAqhApgEwJJgMoqgBQCcQoSBPABxQHk4YBeGAbwCgZ2YUBHAVwEMANgEsoZAMIgAthT6EUhADwAVAHwAKPgC4YSgDQwARtqUBKZjDlQehMDD4N6jAzAC+uthxIALeQDEwyiowalBeQhDG+gBuxmZMMAD0AFQAdGlJCa7uLnYQMKCQUCwsolQwRCQgDDClKCB0CMjoWLgExKS1tMVCYFDycHzAKDDYPFSEFaSBnAAefWBoedSSIgqTIPoA1ihk9SNj8uuBQawcnLyCIuJSMnKEwVo6+kY6JtoGICACKHxgHuwJTLcfjCUQSaSyeTTDSRQyxd6fb6-FguYqAnRhPIQLwgHgCNAwMAkGAAcyEUWGv04hGIhBYBWgMBm1TUMX24yOYB4kgM8hUZnoQSiKW8fjAagAjAAmADMJjRmSUmJg2Nx+OptJgAHcRF47IQSdyUL0alUAAaiwj+M2E4m8nokuyE7m8ukM2BkFls0Yc9ogBRcnl8gVCkWhMVqADkfAMwEj8qAA):

```
const fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf = {
    equalityComparer<T>(a: T, b: T) { return a === b },
    otherFn<T> (this: SuperProto<T>, v: T) { /*...*/ },
    otherFn2<T, U> (this: T, v: U) { /*...*/ },
} as const

type Proto = typeof fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf

interface SuperProto<T> extends Omit<Proto, keyof SuperProto<T>> {
    equalityComparer (a: T, b: T): boolean
    // equalityComparer<T> (a: T, b: T): boolean
}

// This should not give an error
const x = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn(123)
const x2 = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn2(123)

// This should error with argument to `otherFn` not being a number
const y = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn('abc')
const y2 = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn2('abc')
```

Comment: So, just to be sure, `fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf` may not be changed and it contains generics **only** in methods, not in declaration? Because this seems like a problem (but more probably my misunderstanding) since all these methods allows *different* Generic for each call, and they are not linked to `Proto` in any way

Comment: @leonardfactory `fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf` is immutable.  It becomes the prototype/`__proto__` of a function that is also generic, and when that happens the method types all share the same type.   So while the methods may ostensibly have different types, in practice it will always be the same as the type of function they become the prototype of (e.g. `function X<T> {}; Object.setPrototypeOf(X, fnUsedInSetProtypeOf) `.

Comment: This looks like `SuperProto<T>` is a *supertype* of `Proto` and not a subtype, so you cant say that `SuperProto<T> extends Proto`; it's the other way around. Why do you need `extends Proto` anyway?  What breaks if you just leave that off?

Comment: For example, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAqhApgEwJJgMoqgBQCcQoSBPABxQHk4YBeGAbwCgZ2YUBHAVwEMANgEsoZAMIgAthT6EUhADwAVAHwAKPgC4YSgDQwARtqUBKZjDlQehMDD4N6jAzAC+uthxIALeQDEwyupQXkIQxmZMMAD0AFQAdAkxUa7uHNHJCXEw3vIwwUJgAOYQ+oICdgLghXk+MMJgKBDZdAAGknheIGiBMGqZJi0sLnZNoJBQANwsLKJUMEQkIAx5lCggdAjI6Fi4BMSkszRw0wVQ8nB8wCgw2DxUhAukPaxp3PzCohLSsvIaxvpGHQmbQGEAgAQoPhgDzsHKEfxqfJhIHaABuICEaCGLDG0HgYAAcjxJNpbvdHiAFGBiQZ5CplptUJgcHgKYdaFNcbAENgoIRSXd5BSFNBCAVCvTGIztiy9ot2XApkA) is all fine as far as I can tell.  What's the issue?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz — these are great thoughts.   The reason for extending the interface from the `const` is to adhere to the DRY principle i.e. not re-stating a function that's already strongly typed, so ensuring consistency.

Comment: I mean, can you specifically show me what goes wrong if you merely leave `extends Proto` off your `SuperProto<T>` definition? Either nothing goes wrong, in which case I'll write it up an answer... or something not present in your question goes wrong, in which case I hope you'll edit the question with enough information to represent the issue.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I see the question isn't clear on that.  The problem is that there are functions on `Proto` that are not on `SuperProto<T>`, and the `extends` alleviates the need 
to duplicate the definitions on `SuperProto` that already exist on `Proto`.

Comment: Could you modify the code in the question to reflect this?  Add a few things whose definitions don't need to change?  And does it work if you change `interface SuperProto<T> extends Proto` to `interface SuperProto<T> extends Omit<Proto, keyof SuperProto<T>>`?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I've added another playground.  The `Omit<>` idea looks great, but the problem seems to be that the templated function is typed with `this: T`, meaning any subsequent arguments aren't strongly typed.  In the example, the `otherFn <T, U> (this: T, value: U)` there are numerous cases where the type `U` should be strongly typed as the `T` of `SuperProto<T>` (in other words, it's almost like a curry - `Proto.otherFn<A, B>` should become `SuperProto<T>.otherFn<A, T>`).

Comment: ... I feel like much of this could be solved by being able to specify the generic type of a function inside another generic e.g. `function X<T> { ... }` in `interface Proto<U> { X: typeof X<U> }`.

Comment: So `otherFn`'s type is not meant to be left alone, but you need to alter it. (I was under the mistaken assumption that the other functions were to be left alone). So you'll have to write it out explicitly.  There's no way to do this in a more DRY way without a feature like [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) that would allow someone to express the relationship between `type Foo = <T>(x:T)=>T` and `type Bar<T> = (x:T)=>T`.  For now there's no way to write one in terms of the other and you'll have to rewrite everything whose type needs to change in this way.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, that's very helpful to know, and I appreciate the effort here.  Feel free to put this last comment into an answer and I'll mark it correct, for the next folks to happen across this question.

Comment: I'll write up an answer but your new code leads to more questions.  The signature `otherFn<T> (this: T, v: T): void` implies that `this` is the same type as the argument, so you want a `SuperProto<number>` to *be* a `number`?  `otherFn2` makes more sense, since those are different and presumably you can just remove `this` since it'll be a `SuperProto<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to keep the problem simple and digestable; the reality is even more complex, namely the function type is this: `otherFn<T> (this: SuperProto<T>, v: T>`. (or one of SuperProto's ancestors).  I'll edit the question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: ... hmm, interesting.  That may actually solve some problems here. (stepping away from the computer for a bit, but will look into it more when I'm back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use this definition of `Proto`:

```
const fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf = {
    equalityComparer<T>(a: T, b: T) { return a === b },
    otherFn<T>(this: SuperProto<T>, v: T) { /*...*/ },
    otherFn2<T, U>(this: T, v: U) { /*...*/ },
} as const

type Proto = typeof fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf
```

You basically want to define `SuperProto<T>` to be such that a generic parameter moves out of the methods and up into `SuperProto<T>` itself, so that instead of a specific type where each method is independently generic, you have a single generic type where each method is specific.  Something like:

```
interface SuperProto<T> {
    equalityComparer(a: T, b: T): boolean
    otherFn(v: T): void
    otherFn2(v: T): void;
}
```

---

Now, you can't declare that `SuperProto<T> extends Proto`.  Such a declaration would require that `SuperProto<T>` be a subtype of `Proto`; any `SuperProto<T>` instance should be usable as a `Proto`.  But your definitions imply that the opposite is true: `Proto` is actually a subtype of `SuperProto<T>` for any `T` you choose.  The compiler can easily recognize this relationship; if you assign a value of type `Proto` to a variable of type, say, `SuperProto<number>`, there will be no error:

```
const superProtoNum: SuperProto<number> = fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf; // okay
const superProtoStr: SuperProto<string> = fnUsedInSetPrototypeOf; // okay
```

So one solution here is to leave off `extends Proto` in the definition of `SuperProto<T>`, and let the compiler handle verifying structural compatibility between the types:

```
const x = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn(123) // okay
const x2 = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn2(123) // okay

const y = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn('abc') // error
const y2 = (v: SuperProto<number>) => v.otherFn2('abc') // error
```

---

Of course this means you will need to fully specify the methods and properties of `SuperProto<T>`, mentioning every method and parameter name twice.  If `Proto` had some methods or properties whose types should stay exactly the same, you could save some writing by declaring

```
interface SuperProto<T> extends Omit<Proto, keyof SuperProto<T>> {
  equalityComparer(a: T, b: T): boolean
  otherFn(v: T): void
  otherFn2(v: T): void; 
}
```

and `SuperProto<T>` would automatically inherit any properties/methods from `Proto` that aren't mentioned explicitly in `SuperProto<T>`.  But since it doesn't look like your definition has any such unchanged methods/properties, `Omit<Proto, keyof SuperProto<T>>` will evaluate to just `{}`, and since all object types are subtypes of `{}` there's no point in writing that; just leave it off.

---

It's clear that you were hoping there would be some way to represent the relationship between `Proto` and `SuperProto<T>` in a concise manner and have the compiler do the work of translating between them.  Unfortunately there isn't currently any such syntax in TypeScript.  That is, given the following types:

```
type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T;
type Bar<T> = (x: T) => T;
```

there's no way to define one in terms of the other.  The types `Foo` and `Bar<T>` are related, but distinct in that their generic parameters are quantified differently.  You can think of `Foo` as being the intersection of `Bar<T>` for every possible `T`.  Or perhaps:

```
type Foo = <T> Bar<T>
```

But this is invalid syntax in TypeScript.  There is an open suggestion, [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), to support "generic values" that act as the intersection of all possible specifications of a generic type.  Right now, generic function types like `Foo` are the only such generic values that exist in TypeScript and they have their own syntax.  If generic values were fully supported, you would be able to derive `Foo` from `Bar` and much more.  And in such a hypothetical version of TypeScript, you might well be able to express `SuperProto<T>` and `Proto` in some less redundant way.  But for now, it's not possible, and the best you'll be able to do is to fully write out the generic-type-with-specific-methods and specific-type-with-generic-methods explicitly.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playgound link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAqhApgEwJJgMoqgBQCcQoSBPABxQHk4YBeGAbwCgZ2YUBHAVwEMANgEsoZAMIgAthT6EUhADwAVAHwAKPgC4YSgDQwARtqUBKZjDlQehMDD4N6jAzAC+uthxIALeQDEwyupQXkIQ2tg8VIREJCCB+gBuxmZMMAD0AFQAdDkZaa7uHDDefmAATMr6iEEhYTqJ2ogp6dm5+W4sLnYQMKCQUCwsolQwMaQMMMMoIHQIyOhYuATEpFO0g0JgUPJwfMAoMBFRY3GqnAAe22BoPdSSIgpTM-BIqJg4eCdrcPoA1ihkZ5HeQnQIqZgedjcfjCUQSaSyeQaYz6Iw6EzaAwgEACFB8MCQ4rBUpqJLo7QJEBCNCEkqEfxlUnJClUtAAbk6gz60BgEEiIJWIAAcjxJOF+dFBQowKKDPJwYw5m9Fp9Bd82el8iBfnwyFzwDy+cdBdgoIRxcbYgpoIRNgBzBUvebvJZfSg0OAatJanV6ljenS1XleEA8ARoGBgEgwO1CBIHfGcQjEQgsbmwc4TJmHCWgmWSOWEFRmejghJZOn+NQARjKAGYTGmDRmylmycDJVb84XiwwyxXifTyjX643-fklEGICGwxH5CmYAB3EReOyEO2ilBbSYgGAAA0rYD3kejcvtdkjsvkTf6MDIbYtAq7V6LJf7h7UAHI+AZgJ-G+md6tow2YdnmL69qWMDloejLfr+-6DFMMC+NiEyBGo5zJH2OgcshABCsiBFmWHojhSgciwQA)